# Why is "no signal" shown on the monitor when I turn on my computer

Tags: display

When I turn on my Compaq computer, the monitor says no signal.

I checked the cable and I believe it's fine.

If I plug in another Compaq, it does the same thing.  When I plug the monitor into my HP, it works just fine.

Comment: What does happen when you turn the computer on? Does it beep? Do the fans spin up? Does it boot up with no display? (You can tell by listening for the Windows sound or looking for intelligent flashing on the hard drive activity LED.)

Comment: A bit more information would be nice. What exact computers are you using, what do they do, what is connected to them, which operating systems do you use?

Comment: Strange question but do the compaqs have additional graphics cards and you're plugging into the onboard one? It sounds odd but I've seen it done way too many times to discount

Answer (score 1):

Either of

- Your monitor cable has a fault, when you plug it into the HP, the connector is at a different angle, so the strain on the cable is different, so a wire or solder-joint that is broken is pushed back into place sufficiently to allow a signal through.
- Your Compaqs use VGA but the HP uses DVI or HDMI and you neglected to mention this :-)

Comment: Strange question but do the compaqs have additional graphics cards and you're plugging into the onboard one? It sounds odd but I've seen it done way too many times to discount.